# Image in HTML mail resized parent object

Tags: html, css, email

I have an HTML mail which includes a header. It works all fine till the point the images are included. The header is bigger than the relatively sized table. When I then allow Outlook to include the externaly hosted images the header causes the parent object to resize and this screws the whole thing up.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: Calibri;">
        <tr>
                <td width="28%">
                </td>
                <td width="44%">
                        <img src="http://www.domain.com/header.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
```

I found several websites saying that `style="width: 100%; height: auto;"` will fix it but it doesn't. How can I fit the image in the parent object instead of resizing the parent object?

Answer (score 0):

with an empty last cell it's works fine for me, it permit to have the 100% width required by the table

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="one"></td>
    <td class="two">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td class="empty"></td>
  </tr>

</table>


table{
  width:100%;
  background: grey;
  font-size:0;
}

.one{
  width:25%;
  background: blue;
}

.two{
  width:50%;
  background: green;
}

img{
  width: 100%; 
  height:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4822s7w2/

Answer (score 0):

Set the table width to a fixed value (say 250px) instead of 100% which is a relative value. Then you can size it accordingly.
Also I would suggest using `<div>` instead of tables.

Comment: using what instead of tables? :D

Comment: Initially i die Thatcher but then it was a mess to Center that div